# How to use if statement in array map function with next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx, conditional-operator

if the remainder from the index number is 0, I want to wrap the code I need to show below and below. How can I do this? I tried like the ones below but it didn't work. I'm getting a syntax error.

{index% 3 == 0? ...: ...}

{index% 3 == 0 && ...}

```
export default function UserPosts() {
    // some code...
    return (
        <div className={styles.userPosts}>
            {postsList.map((post, index) => {
                return (
                    if (index % 3 == 0) {
                        <div className={styles.userPostsRow}>
                    }
                    <div className={styles.userPostWrapper}>
                        <div className={styles.userPostColumn}>
                            <Link href={`/${username}`}>
                                <a>
                                    <div className={styles.userPost}>
                                        <img src={post.image} alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    if (index % 3 == 0) {
                        </div>
                    }
                )                
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reduce JSX duplication, you could extract the conditional logic to a component that would wrap the children components.

```js
const ConditionalWrapper = ({ children, condition }) => {
    return condition ? (
        <div className={styles.userPostsRow}>{children}</div>
    ) : (
        children
    )
}

export default function UserPosts() {
    // some code...

    return (
        <div className={styles.userPosts}>
            {postsList.map((post, index) => {
                return (
                    <ConditionalWrapper condition={index % 3 == 0}>
                        <div className={styles.userPostWrapper}>
                            <div className={styles.userPostColumn}>
                                <Link href={`/${username}`}>
                                    <a>
                                        <div className={styles.userPost}>
                                            <img src={post.image} alt="" />
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </ConditionalWrapper>
                )                
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Inside your `return` statement, you need to use JSX. Conditionals in JSX can take different forms, these are some I prefer:

**If something exists ( implicit `&&`)**:

```js
{ arr.map( (item) => {
  return(
    item.condition &&
    <div className="whatever">Your Content</div>
  )
})}
```

**If a condition is met (condition with `&&`)**

```js
{ arr.map( (item, index) => {
  return(
    item.index % 3 &&
    <div className="whatever">Your Content</div>
  )
})}
```

**If/else block (use ternary `? () : ()`)**

```js
{ arr.map( (item, index) => {
  return(
    item.index % 3 ? (
      <>
        <div className="whatever">True catch condition</div>
        <div className="whatever">Multiple HTML lines</div>
      </>   
    ) : (
      <div className="whatever">False catch condition</div> 
    )
  )
})}
```

Comment: When I do as you mentioned above, the last part of the code is not colored in my editor and it actually works incorrectly. I think the reason why it fails here is because the div element is closed directly below. It seems to me that jsx cannot understand it is opened above.


Editor: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/793604426144415778/797915036361556018/unknown.png

Working image: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/793604426144415778/797915922613665812/unknown.png

Comment: There are a couple errors in your code. You want to wrap your entire ternary expression in `()`. And in JSX, all HTML is read as JS (which can be confusing if you're new to it). As such, you can only return one object at a time. So you need to wrap all of your HTML in React Fragments `<></>` - these consolidate your HTML into an object. I updated my example to show you, check it out.